# Frame by frame animation problems with Gingerbread 2.3.6

Tags: android, android-drawable

Objective:

Frame by frame animation on an ImageButton without the user having to "click" it, all through xml as well. This has already been accomplished, but it won´t work for Android 2.3.6, and I can´t for the life of me, figure out why.

Set up:

The project is clean, there´s nothing else but a main activity and an **ImageButton** within that main activity.

**Main activity:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/main_tree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/main_tree"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/growing_tree" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, the ImageButton points to the **drawable growing_tree**, an xml **SELECTOR**.

**growing_tree**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim_growing_tree" 
         android:state_enabled="true"    />

</selector>
```

And this one in turn points to the actual frame by frame animation.

**anim_growing_tree**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:oneshot="false">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree1" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree2" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree3" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree4" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree5" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree6" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree7" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree8" android:duration="150"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree9" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree10" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree11" android:duration="150" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tree12" android:duration="150" />

</animation-list>
```

It´s all quite straight forward. Just in case I´ll add the **manifest** file too.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.marstudio.memorytree"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.marstudio.memorytree.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

When I run it with an emulator of a Nexus-S with android 4.2.2 it works fine, as soon as the screen comes on the frame by frame animation begins.

Both .xml files are under **res/drawable**

Now when I run it on a real device with Gingerbread 2.3.6 the screen comes on **but the it stays on the first frame, the animation won´t continue**. What could I be doing wrong? I´d really appreciate some input!

Comment: When are you calling `start()` on the `AnimationDrawable`?

Comment: I don´t need, that´s why I have the <selector>. It enables the Imagebutton and the animation starts on its own.

Comment: Well, apparently it doesn't on Android 2.3. :-) Try dropping a `start()` call into your code and see if it has an impact. If it does, that's probably your solution.

Comment: I know how to do it with the start() XD, I just wanted to know why it doesn´t work with the xml-only method on 2.3.6, you know, to learn I guess. XD

Comment: Ah, I see. My guess is that it's just something that was added in API Level 11.

Comment: Have your tried below code, view_you_want_to_animate.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar-ish problem; I tested my application on 3 different live devices and here's my conclusions.

If I declared my animation drawable to be the background of an ImageView in an XML layout file, it'd work fine on Google Nexus 4 but on HTC One and Sony Xperia Z1 it would basically show the 1st frame and not animate at all.

Yes, the OS versions on all the phones are different (HTC One hasn't got 4.4 yet, for example) but since you've had a similar problem on 2 completely different versions of Android, this leads me to believe that there's some major differences in how the code behaves under different Android flavours - i.e. you have to start the animations "properly" for them to work on all phones.

Example code snippet:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    splashImageViewAnimatedBeep = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashImageBeep);
    splashImageViewAnimatedBeep.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_animation_beep);
    splashAnimationImageViewBeep = (AnimationDrawable) splashImageViewAnimatedBeep.getBackground();
    splashAnimationImageViewBeep.start();
}
```